# Porque o meu botão não funciona?

Tags: javascript

```js
function click(){
  console.log('clicou')    
}
```

```html
   <div id="primeira">
        Números (entre 1 e 100): <input type="number" name="" id="tab"> 
        <input type="button" id="but" value="Adicionar" onclick="click()">
    </div>
```

Queria saber porque o click() não funciona

Comment: muda o nome da função, em vez de click pode ser clicks ou qq outro nome que não seja reservado

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode usar qualquer palavra-chave reservada como nome de variável ou função. Isso inclui todas as palavras-chave atualmente usadas pela linguagem e todas as outras mantidas em reservado para versões futuras do JavaScript. Os projetistas do JavaScript, no entanto, não podem prever cada palavra-chave que a linguagem poderá utilizar no futuro. Usando o tipo de palavra isolada que atualmente aparece na lista de palavras-chave reservadas, você corre o risco de um conflito no futuro.

Devido ao conflito em potencial com palavras-chave futuras, o uso de combinações de palavras para nomes de variáveis é sempre uma boa ideia. Combinação de palavras provavelmente não aparecem na lista de palavras reservadas.

Você poderá usar uma das convenções para associar varias palavras como uma. Uma convenção é colocar um caractere de sublinhado entre as palavras; outra é iniciar a palavra combinada com uma letra maiúscula, dentro do nome composto. Estes dois exemplos são nomes de variável válidos:

```
    minhaVar   minha_var
```

Os nomes de variáveis possuem algumas outras restrições importantes. Evite todos os símbolos, exceto pelo caractere de sublinhado. Além disso, o primeiro caractere de nome de variável não pode ser um numero.

```js
function minhaFunction(){
   console.log('clicou')    
}
```

```html
<div id="primeira">
    Números (entre 1 e 100): <input type="number" name="" id="tab"> 
    <input type="button" id="but" value="Adicionar" onclick="minhaFunction()">
</div>
```

Palavra reservada `case` observe que vai dar um erro

```js
function case(){
   console.log('clicou')    
}
```

```html
    <div id="primeira">
    Números (entre 1 e 100): <input type="number" name="" id="tab"> 
    <input type="button" id="but" value="Adicionar" onclick="case()">
```

> Usei muito a palavra variável mas tudo que foi dito serve para função.

**Fonte** JavaScript a Bíblia

[Lista de palavras reservadas](https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_reserved.asp)